# @WebServlet("/*") error searching for a .jsp

Tags: java

```
@WebServlet("/*")
public class Venta extends HttpServlet

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/ventas.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

when putting the asterisk `*` in the annotations, it is as if all the jsp of the application will disappear.

> error org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter
> (WsFilter.java:53)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would work, try:

```
import javax.servlet.annotations.WebServlet;

@WebServlet(name="Venta", urlPatterns={"/*"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a servlet, shouldn't you be trying to implement a filter?

```
@WebFilter("/*", dispatcherTypes={DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD})
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
       request.getRequestDispatcher("/ventas.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
  }
```

You can see more in: https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/webfilter-annotation-examples
or an example of implementation: https://www.javaguides.net/2019/02/webfilter-annotation-example.html